# Does flutter support Google Assistant Read It feature?

Tags: flutter, google-assistant-sdk

I want to build an app that contains some web content readable data. and I want to allow the users to read or listen to the content. google assistant read it is allowing to do that. Does flutter support Google Assistant **Read It** feature?

Answer (score 2):

Flutter may not directly support a particular Android feature directly but will allow you to implement [Read It](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/read-it) through the `onProvideAssistContent` method you'd need to implement through something like [`MethodChannel`](https://medium.com/@Chetan/flutter-communicate-with-android-activity-or-ios-viewcontroller-through-method-channel-c11704429cd0) or a [native plugin](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) to call the platform-specific code.